# Suggestions and Intellicode no longer working after changing color theme in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

what I did is just changed the color theme and after that, it is stopped working as expected regular behavior, It is **not showing suggestions**, **VS Code IntelliCode** also not working as before I have done efforts of my side as like uninstalled all extensions and installed them again, deleted VS Code from applications and installed it again.  [Image You can see the extensions which are using currently and also you can observe that I'm using the style of **justify-content** when I typed the quotes then it is supposed to show all the values available for it. but it is not showing currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNEfZ.png)

Please let me know, are there any possible ways to get back to the normal behavior of VS Code for Mac?
I already uninstalled all the extensions and installed them again, removed VS Code from Applications. and downloaded the latest version from the official VS Code site.

Comment: Try to see if the extension are enabled or uninstall and install extensions again

Comment: all extensions are enabled only. and also uninstalled and installed all extensions

Comment: I doubt it is because of the theme, but for completeness, what theme did you change into?

Comment: Dark+ (default dark)